# Mac not searching my files

Tags: finder, spotlight, search

Today I started my Mac (iMac) and when I tried to search in finder or spotlight it produce no results. I think its related to the search cache. I guess it gets corrupted. If this is the case How can I regenerate the cache or fix this issue.

Comment: Can you tell us a little about your Spotlight prefs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
To display the status of indexing
# mdutil -s /
To clear the metadata store
Turn indexing off for /
# mdutil -i off /
Clear the metadata store for /
# mdutil -E /
Turn indexing back on for /
# mdutil -i on /
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to rebuild the Spotlight index.  The easiest way to do that is a freeware app called Onyx.  It also clears caches and performs a number of mac maintenance items.  Search online for Onyx, install the app and click execute the "Automation" tab and let us know how you made out.

Comment: You can easily rebuild the index without command line or other tools by adding the hard drive to the privacy list and then removing it from that list. Click, click, click, done.